# How to send data to php script, which already running?

Tags: php, scripting

I need to send some data to PHP script which listening socket in cycle and receive data from it.
Can I make it without white/read file between scripts?

**Update:**
There are two PHP scripts; one script listening for anything e.g. telnet, secondary script must send data to first script which will write this data to socket.

Comment: If it's listening on a socket, then connect to that socket and send your data

Comment: Send from where, another script, javascript or another application?

Comment: updated. i need bridge between two running php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - that's pretty much the definition of what the socket is **for**.

What's the problem?

Comment: I'm not exactly expressed. There is two php scripts. One script listening anything e.g telnet, secondary script must send data to first script which will write this data to socket. Peculiar bridge

Comment: telnet is not a listener (server) - its a client